# Java Server Sockets: Find an open port NOT blocked by a firewall

Tags: java, sockets, port, firewall

I have a problem similar to this question which was previously asked but my problem is different.  I need to be able to see if the port is open and not blocked by a firewall automatically.  All examples I found just find ports which the server can be bound to but do not check whether the port is not blocked by a firewall or not.  If it is blocked by a firewall, a client not on the LAN cannot connect to the server.  Does anybody have any method to do this automatically?  I know you can use the CMD in Windows to check ports manually but I need to this automatically.  Thanks and sorry for any confusion.

Comment: How did I get a -1? I researched this for the past hour and no one has any solution that I have found.

Comment: Ask the person who configured / administers the firewall. Without going into great detail there's no easy way to do this from the machine itself, whatever it is you think CMD in windows does .. it doesn't. You could also use a port scanner running on a remote host (or one that can reroute packets) ... though someone might notice that.

Comment: This isn't normally possible, unless you can get a client on the other side of the firewall to cooperate with you in testing. It would be quicker to ask the firewall admin. Firewalls are not generally very cooperative in telling you their settings automatically.

Comment: You can use a port scanner to find open ports. But determining whether the port would be blocked by a firewall is platform and firewall dependent.

Comment: If this were easy to do, wouldn't that make the firewall pointless in the first place?

Comment: Not entirely, since the blocked ports would still be blocked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not manual but a bit outside of Java, but you can run NMAP and then read the results into java.  This will help you understand what ports are open.

Comment: Useful tip but I have no idea even how this could be done... I guess I will just make people do this manually. Thanks

Comment: research a bit on how to run system commands in java and then just read the docs on nmap..its pretty easy actually. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Java and Nmap you can use nmap4j.sourceforge.net, it's a Java API for running Nmap and parses the results into Java objects for you.